# Convert UniSwap ID from Graph Query to position token id

Tags: uniswapv3, the-graph

I'm sure, the answer is very simple, still I can't figure it out.

I know I can get a list of all active UniSwap positions (not closed) positions by querying the subgraph (I'm on Arbitrum):

```
query active_positions {
  positions(
    where: {account: "someaccount", timestampClosed: null}
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

What I get is an ID, which looks like this:

"0x00000000001e990a00"

What I need, is a uint256 (like "807345") to pass to the NonfungiblePositionManager smart contract. How do I convert (I'm using python).

Thanks in advance!
Kurt